# (SQLite + Qt + CodeBlock) How to make these 3 works?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qt-creator, codeblocks

I am currently doing a project using Code::Block (Reason: portability compared to QtCreator. I can't install QtCreator at school so I put Code::Block in a USB Key and it works.)

Here is my query: Do a Qt based GUI app to store Clients.
How to store Clients? SQLite.

So here's the problem:

I have 37 errors while trying to match the three (QT, SQLite and CodeBlock). All errors look the same (with different number and QObjects):

> undifined reference to 'imp___ZN9QSqlQueryD1Ex'

I found the answer to my question, part of. It is when you use QtCreator+SQLite:

> After not getting it to work, I checked with the Qt Community Forum and it seems that all I was missing was
>
> QT += sql
>
> in the .pro file
>
> Here is the forum post: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/8262/

So after trying what he said (copy+paste in QtCreator my project), and added "QT += sql" to the .pro file in QtCreator, it works like a charm.

Still I wish to use Code::Block, and there is no .pro files to do this "magic trick".

**Anybody has ideas how to match Qt+SQLite+CodeBlocks?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't use C::B but you should be able to link against the QtSql static library. This is essentially what for AFAIK `QT += sql` does on the .pro/QtCreator side.